# Cannot connect to MSSQL server management studio as localhost

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I installed MSSQL server 2016 with configuration manager and management studio. I trying connect to SQL server via management studio:

- Server type: Database Engine
- Server name: localhost
- Authentication: Windows Authentication

Error TITLE: Connect to Server:

> Cannot connect to localhost. A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2) The
>   system cannot find the file specified

Nothing more information in event viewer. I have these services with states:

- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) - Running
- SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (SQLEXPRESS) - Running
- SQL Server Launchpad (SQLEXPRESS) - Running
- SQL Server Reporting Services (SQLEXPRESS) - Running
- SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) - Stopped
- SQL Server Browser - Running

After try start SQL Server Agent i get this error:

> The SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) service on Local Computer started
>   and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in
>   use by other services or programs.

Thank you for any advice.

### EDIT

I capture a screen of sql services:
[image]

Comment: Might be the installation process is not completely done?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of all the services of `SQL Server Agent` like :protocols services and Service

Comment: The default instance name of Express, if not changed during setup, is `SQLEXPRESS`, which means you have to connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i addent to original post that screenshot. How can i know if installation process was completely done?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I know but how can i change connection instante of management studio?

Comment: Set the server name to 'local' or '.' (just a dot) or your computer name.

Comment: Sql Server Service from SQL Server Configuration Manager --> Protocol for SQL Express

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I have turn on TCP/IP protocol with 443... Now i tried instead of localhost used server name: .\sqlexpress and everything working. I am little bit confused because before reinstal MSSQL i had 2017 and server name was localhost. If i am not wrong i dont change server name. Maybe yes, probably but i am not sure.. BTW thank you so much for your time and advice :)

Comment: When all else fails I'll connect to the SQL box I'm on as `127.0.0.1` by passing any kind of name lookup and going directly by IP address.

Comment: Note: SQL Agent is not supported in Express Editions; that service will never run.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In an attempt to get all the answers in one spot (and hopefully help a future searcher), you can connect to the SQL box that SQL Management Studio is installed on by changing the `Server name:` in the connection dialog

[image]

to one of the following:

- `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`
- `.`
- `127.0.0.1` - by direct IP address, this is your loopback IP
- The actual IP address of the machine
- The name of the machine you are on, several ways to figure this out. https://www.cnet.com/how-to/find-out-your-computers-name-and-windows-edition-in-two-clicks/
- The named instance of SQL you have locally installed, in this case: `.\SQLEXPRESS`
- The machine name and the SQL instance like: `YOURCOMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS2017`
- `LOCALHOST`

Comment: had the same issue and using `.\MSQLEXPRESS` solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: using .\SQLEXPRESS solved the problem. Thanks. SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 34):

I could solve the same issue only with server name `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`. Just FYI

Answer (score 3):

May be this is familiar to many, but I believe new starters may find this helpful! As similar like above snapshot provided in the problem, I did not find MSSQLSERVER service is showing in SQL Server Configuration Manager. The reason is that I just installed the exe, but failed to do sql server setup actually! To make my 'localhost' as server name with windows authentication works, I followed below steps.

1. Open SQL Server 2019 Installation Centre. [Note: For SQL Server Installation Media Path, choose location [C:\SQL2019\Express_ENU](https://C:%5CSQL2019%5CExpress_ENU)]. This will open installation Wizard.
2. Go to Installation -> Choose 'New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation'
3. In Installation Type -> Choose 'Perform a new installation of SQL Server 2019'
4. Follow the instructions and in between the setup, it will **prompt to setup password for 'sa'. You can choose either windows mode or mixed mode** ( i.e. windows and sql server authentication). [NOTE: This sa password setup will not be prompted during installation from exe.]
5. Complete the setup.
6. Once completed, you can see 'MSSQLSERVER' is running.
7. Just type in 'localhost' with windows authentication by default.
8. This time, just enter 'localhost' in server name like below
   [image]
9. It will then connected immediately without any hassles.
   [image: local host db connected]

Answer (score 0):

Go the given link and download developer edition -
once you have installed it, then you would see something like below -

From below picture you can find the server name, that you connect locally.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YaS4.png)

Yo can also refer to my answer on - https://www.quora.com/profile/Sania-Fatimi/Installing-SQL-server-Developer-edition-SSMS-and-connecting-to-localhost-local-server-Go-the-given-link-and-downloa